# 40 columns in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Is 40 columns in MySQL table too much? This table is used for store user informations data. This table will never joins with next table. So I think it is ok.

What do you think ?

Thanks!

Comment: is ok, go ahead. Do you know about normalization pros/cons?https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=normalization+pros%2Fcons&oq=normalization+pros%2Fcons&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Normalization is key.

Answer (score 0):

It's just data. So the overall size (rows + columns) is what should matter to you.

If you find that you need a lot of columns for your data and not every row fills in every column, you may benefit by using a nosql document store.

Comment: So If I will have 1 000 000 rows with 40columns it is still ok ?

Comment: ok is a subjective term. you may have capacity and performance requirements that are important to you that must be addressed.